# What is the meaning of the part in bold in the following sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

The Jan Lokpal Bill (Citizen's ombudsman Bill) is a draft anti-corruption bill drawn up by prominent civil society activists seeking the appointment of a Jan Lokpal, an independent body that would investigate corruption cases, complete the investigation within a year and **envisages trial in the case getting over in the next one year**.

I have seen the meaning of envisage, but I couldn't understand the meaning of last part of sentence.

Read more at: http://www.ndtv.com/article/india/what-is-the-jan-lokpal-bill-why-its-important-96600&cp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, before anything else is said, it has to be pointed out that that is a *horrid* sentence.

It seems to mean that they want the trial to be completed within 12 months.

Comment: Not just *one* trial, but the trial for each corruption case that is investigated by the Jan Lokpal, as I read it.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, even though that's not actually what it says.

Comment: When it says **the next one year** maybe it means the investigation is completed within one year, and the trial with the year after that ??

Answer (score 2):

It's very badly written, but they mean they hope the **trial will be completed within the next 12 months**.